# qt signal-slot multithreading deadlocks

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

In my code a worker thread emits a signal to gui thread. Signal and Slot are connected via Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection.

When during the`closeEvent` application is trying to stop the worker thread and only then finishes the event.

It calls the function of worker thread:

```
void stop() {
  _isFinished = true;
  wait();
}
```

The worker thread in its turn checks `_isFinished` condition and if it is not set up then emit the signal.

Imaging the following situation

```
The worker            Gui Thread 
=================     =================
if (!_isFinished)     -----------------
-----------------     _isFinished = true;
-----------------     wait();
emit mySignal();      -----------------
```

Evidently, both threads would be locked - deadlock.

If I add a mutex then you can find another deadlock situation. When the worker locks the mutex and the gui thread would be blocked. As a result the emitted signal will lock the worker.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you use BlockingQueuedConnection rather than QueuedConnection?

Comment: Yes, it is important, because the slot which is connected to the signal needs to release memory objects, in other case the memory overflow occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see the situation.

In your main thread you do not need to wait for worker to quit. Instead your `closeEvent` should look like this:

```
if (workerThread->isRunning())
{
    workerThread->stop();
    event->ignore();
}
```

To make this work, you also need to close main window, when worker thread finishes:

```
connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(close()));
```

Finally, all manipulations with `_isFinished` (and all other variables in worker thread) should occur in worker thread. You can achieve it with a simple trick:

**WorkerThread.h**

```
public:
    void stop();

protected slots:
    void p_stop();

protected:
    QMutex mutex;
```

**WorkerThread.cpp**

```
void WorkerThread::stop()
{
    staticMetaObject.invokeMethod(this, "p_stop", Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void WorkerThread::p_stop();
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    _isFinished = true;
}
```

This way you can avoid deadlocks.

Comment: For some reason, `close()` slot is not always executed. So, I need to press close button twice (sometimes). But the worker thread finishes. How this could happen? Why the `finished` signal is not emitted?

Comment: Could you add your `WorkingThread::run()` method to the question?

Answer (score 0):

In the gui thread you can use QEventLoop for wait. Look like this:

```cpp
void stop() {
    QEventLoop eventloop;
    connect(&theWorkerThread, &QThread::finished, &eventloop, QEventLoop::quit);
    _isFinished = true;
    eventloop.exe();
}
```