# QThread::finished() not emitted or QWidget::close() not invoked

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots

The original problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741432/qt-signal-slot-multithreading-deadlocks/16742221?noredirect=1#16742221). I understood the offered solution and I think it should work. But not everything has gone well. I have problem that `QThread::finished` is not always emitted or `QWidget::close()` is not always invoked for some reasons. i.e sometimes I need to press the close button twice. It works on the second press because the worker thread is finished on the first one and in `closeEvent` the event is not ignored anymore.

This problem happens only when I am trying to close the application straight after the main window is visible. If I wait couple of seconds the application closes on the first click.

P.S. The worker thread is infinite.

**UPDATE**

Run Method for worker

```
virtual void
run() {
  PRINT("Simulation Started at Thread %d", QThread::currentThread());
  _isFinished = false;
  double position = 0.0;

  // Some calculations

  emit updated();

  while (!_isFinished) {
    _mutex.lock();

    if (_isPaused)
      _waitCondition.wait(&_mutex);

    _mutex.unlock();

    if (_isFinished)
      break;

    QThread::msleep(_delay);

    // some calculations;

    emit updated();

  }

  PRINT("Simulation Finished");
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your thread's `run` method?

Comment: How much is `_delay`? I guess it might be the problem.

Comment: I can change it from 0 to whatever. But usually it is in range from 50 to 300.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the real reason of your problem, but here's several thoughts, that might help.

Since you start your thread only once, it would be better to move `_isFinished = false;` line to your constructor, in case you are trying to close application before this initialization.

I also recommend to to protect `_isFinished` variable with mutex.

```
bool WorkerThread::isFinished() const
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    return _isFinished;
}
```

If `_delay` variable is needed to avoid 100% CPU loading, it is not necessary to make it too big. Even 1 ms usually is enough.

Comment: Ive done what you suggested, but the problem has not gone. Do you know any reason why `close()` cannot receive `finished()` signal? Because I am confident that `finished()` is sent.

Comment: What if the signal is received, while `closeEvent` is still running? Try to add `msleep(100)` at the end of `run` method, right before exiting.

Comment: I tried, did not solve. The situation you described could not happen, because there is no concurrency. The `close()` would be invoke in the gui thread, because of `Qt::AutoConnection - (default) If the signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving object, the signal is queued, behaving as Qt::QueuedConnection. Otherwise, the slot is invoked directly, behaving as Qt::DirectConnection. The type of connection is determined when the signal is emitted.`